# Async storage array not saving last entered element

Tags: react-native, local-storage, asyncstorage

I am new to react-native I am trying to port my react app to react-native however I tried to make data persistent with Async Storage. But the problem is Async Storage stored array is always one element less than the state array. I am trying to store the local state array with async storage.

Edit: Here is app.js:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow strict-local
 */

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  Dimensions,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  ImageBackground,
} from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';


import Header from './Components/Header';
import CreateArea from './Components/CreateArea';
import Note from './Components/Note';

let width=Dimensions.get('window').width;
const image={uri:"https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/concrete-wall-3.png"}

function App(){
  const[notes,setNotes]=useState([]);

  const saveData=async(newNote)=>{
    try{
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('notes',JSON.stringify(notes))
      alert('data saved successfully')
      setNotes(prevNotes=>{
        return [...prevNotes,newNote]
      })
      
    }catch(err){
      alert(err.message)
    }
  }
  
  const readData=async()=>{
    try {
      const fetchNotes=await AsyncStorage.getItem('notes')
      // console.log(fetchNotes)
      setNotes(JSON.parse(fetchNotes))
    } catch (error) {
        alert(error.message)
    }
  }

  function deleteNote(id){
    setNotes(prevNotes=>{
      return prevNotes.filter((noteItem,index)=>{
        return index != id;
      })
    })
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    readData()
  },[])

  return (
    <View style={styles.View}>
      <Header />
      <CreateArea onAdd={saveData} />
      <ImageBackground source={image} style={styles.image} />
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.Notes}>
        {notes.map((noteItem, index)=>{
          return(
            <Note 
              key={index}
              id={index}
              title={noteItem.title}
              content={noteItem.content}
              onDelete={deleteNote}
            />
          )
        })}
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  )
}

export default App;

const styles=StyleSheet.create({
  View:{
    flex:1,
    fontFamily:'Helvetica',
  },
  image:{
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    resizeMode:'cover',
    justifyContent:'center'
  },
  Notes:{
    flexDirection:'row',
    width:width,
    flexWrap:'wrap'
  }
})
```

Edit: Here is CreateArea component:

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import { TextInput, View, Button, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

function CreateArea(props){
    const [note,setNote]=useState({
        title:"",
        content:""
    });

    const [isExpanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

    function handleTitle(text){
        setNote(prevNote => {
            return {
              ...prevNote,
              title: text
            };
        });
    }

    function handleContent(text){
        setNote(prevNote => {
            return {
              ...prevNote,
              content: text
            };
        });
    }

    function submitNote(event){
        props.onAdd(note);
        setNote({
            title:"",
            content:""
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    function expand(){
        setExpanded(true)
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.createNote}>
            {isExpanded?(<TextInput 
                            name="title" 
                            value={note.title} 
                            placeholder="Title" 
                            onChangeText={handleTitle}
                        />)
                        : null}
            <TextInput 
                multiline={true} 
                numberOfLines={4} 
                name="content" value={note.content} 
                placeholder="Take a note..." 
                onFocus={expand} 
                onChangeText={handleContent} 
            />
            <Button style={styles.createNoteButton} title='Add note' onPress={submitNote} />
        </View>
    )
}

export default CreateArea;

let width=Dimensions.get('window').width;
const styles=StyleSheet.create({
    createNote:{
        position:'relative',
        width:width,
        marginTop: 30,
        marginRight:'auto',
        marginBottom:20,
        marginRight:'auto',
        backgroundColor:'#fff',
        padding:15,
        borderRadius:7,
        elevation:5
    },
    createNoteButton:{
        position:'absolute',
        right:18,
        bottom:-18,
        backgroundColor:'#f5ba13',
        color:'#fff',
        // border:'none',
        width:36,
        height:36,
        elevation:3,
        // outline:false
    }
})
```

Edit: Here is the Note component

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button, View, Text, StyleSheet, Dimensions} from 'react-native';

let width=Dimensions.get('window').width;

function Note(props){
    function handlePress(){
        props.onDelete(props.id);
    }

    return(
        <View style={styles.Note}>
            <Text style={styles.H1}>{props.title}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.P}>{props.content}</Text>
            <Button style={styles.Button} title="delete" onPress={handlePress} />
        </View>
    )
}

export default Note

const styles=StyleSheet.create({
    Note:{
        backgroundColor:'#fff',
        borderRadius:7,
        elevation:5,
        padding:10,
        width:width*0.45,
        margin:10,
        // float:'left'
    },
    H1:{
        fontSize:18,
        marginBottom:6
    },
    P:{
        fontSize:12,
        marginBottom:10,
        // whiteSpace:'pre-wrap',
        // wordWrap:'break-word'
    },
    Button:{
        position:'relative',
        // float:'right',
        marginRight:10,
        color: '#f5ba13',
        width:36,
        height:36,
    }
})
```

The react app I am trying to port can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-pre-built-react-components-zxh7h)

As I said I am a noob in react-native any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks anyway

Comment: Can you please add the full code of both the components? It's really difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a useEffect hook, with notes as a dependency and to set your AsyncStorage item into this useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (notes.length) {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('notes')
          .then((prevNotes) => {
            AsyncStorage.setItem('notes', JSON.stringify([...JSON.parse(prevNotes), ...notes]))
          })
    }
}, [notes])
```

This way, when *notes* value is updated, you'll always automatically persist the new value in AsyncStorage.

Comment: Thanks for helping but now everything resets on reloading the app

Comment: I edited my answer, let me know if it works better !

Comment: Still after reloading all the notes disappear

Answer (score 0):

i was having the same issue

i used useEffect to saveItem whenever notes state changed

like this

```js
const addItem = async(note) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("@notesStorage", JSON.stringify(note));

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
useEffect(() => {
  addItem(notes);
}, [notes])
```